# How to switch dotnet core webapp to development mode under IIS

Tags: exception, iis, .net-core

I have a `dotnet core 3.1` application hosted under `IIS`, so the environment variables are set like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_URLS" value="https://dev.mycompany.com/MyApp" />
          <environmentVariable name="LOCAL" value="false" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

When an error is thrown, I see this:

[image]

Given the app is deployed under IIS, what can I do to show the actual exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Startup.cs, make the following changes:

```
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // Following enables exception page
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
```

The above line will enable developer exception page only for debug environment. You can put the line app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); outside of if to show exception and stack trace always.

If the app is already deployed, you cannot directly get the exception message.

Another thing I do if I have access to the hosting machine. I log into the hosting machine and try to access the service with localhost url, http://localhost:{port}. This forces dotnet to assume it is a local developer environment and then displays the exception message.